# How check any value of array exist in another array php?

Tags: php

I have two array

```
$a = array('a','b');
$b = array('a','1','2','3','4');
```

How to checks any value of array $a exists in array $b without using loop?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
if (count(array_intersect($array1, $array2)) === 0) {
  // No values from array1 are in array 2
} else {
  // There is at least one value from array1 present in array2
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

*Probably worth nothing that, in all likelihood, under the hood, a loop is used.*

Comment: But, that loop is probably better than my loop.

Comment: Works great and nice solution.

Comment: To be fair, this statement will continue if the values of `$array1` are _not_ in `$array2`. You'll want to negate the comparison operator to determine if one of them is.