# How to check if the same value exists in two arrays with php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How check any value of array exist in another array php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789897/how-check-any-value-of-array-exist-in-another-array-php)

I am creating a shopping site. To simplify, I have 2 arrays, one holds all my items and the other holds all the items that are added on the cart :

**$Items**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Verity soap caddy
            [price] => 6.00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Kier 30cm towel rail
            [price] => 14.00
        )
      //a lot more
)
```

**$cartItems**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 6.00
            [name] => Verity soap caddy
            [subtotal] => 6
        )
)
```

I would like to loop through the **$cartItems** and add a class (identify) if an item is also in the cart. This is how I tried to do it

```
foreach($items as $items){
  if($cartItems[$items->id]['id']){
    echo '<h1 class="inCart">'. $item->title . '</h1>' //...
   }else{
    echo '<h1>'. $item->title . '</h1>' //...
   }
}
```

The above code does not work - even though `$cartItems[0]['id']` would return what I need. My thinking is, whilst looping through $items, check if the similar id exists in the `$cartItems` array. I also tried to add `$cartItems[$i]['id']` and increment `$i` within the loop, and that did not work.
Of course the html output that I wanted to get is (simplified)

```
<h1 class="IsOnCart"> Item Title</h1>
<h1> Item Title</h1>
<h1 class="IsOnCart"> Item Title</h1>
<h1> Item Title</h1>
```

Is there a way to implement this?
Thanks

Comment: You should look at the right sidebar of related questions, as your question has already been asked and answered.

Comment: but that is giving me an error of "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string". maybe because the other question does not ask multidimensional arrays??

Comment: Most probably not a problem, but your code here has a syntax error: [$items->id]['id] should be: [$items->id]['id']

Comment: @art2 I did not make that mistake on my original code, so that's not it

Comment: I wonder what other mistakes you made here that are not "on your original code"? How are we to know? Shall we just identify problems one at a time until you stop saying "that's not it"? I don't have time... Post your _testcase_, _verbatim_. No typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$intersection = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
if (in_array($value, $intersection)) {
    // both arrays contain $value
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error though "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: Yes because this answer is not specific for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$items = array(
  0 => 
  (object) (array(
     'id' => 1,
     'title' => 'Verity soap caddy',
     'price' => '6.00',
  )),
  1 => 
  (object) (array(
     'id' => 2,
     'title' => 'Kier 30cm towel rail',
     'price' => '14.00',
  )),
);


$cartItems = array(
        0 => array(
                'rowid' => 'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b',
                'id' => 1,
                'qty' => 1,
                'price' => '6.00',
                'name' => 'Verity soap caddy',
                'subtotal' => 6,
        ),
);

$itemsIncart = array_reduce(array_uintersect($items, $cartItems, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = (array) $a;
    $b = (array) $b;
    return $a['id'] === $b['id'] ? 0 : 1;
}), function ($a, $b) {
    $a[$b->id] = true;
    return $a;
});

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if (array_key_exists($item->id, $itemsIncart))
        printf('<h1 class="inCart">%s *</h1>', $item->title);
    else
        printf('<h1>%s</h1>', $item->title);
}
```

Output

```
<h1 class="inCart">Verity soap caddy</h1>
<h1>Kier 30cm towel rail</h1>
```